Estimating the minimal number of changes needed to fix a syntax error in "code"
I am wondering if there is an existing library that computes the following:
Imagine I give you a [string of] code (e.g., Python or any other formal language specified with a grammar) with some potential syntax error. Is there a way to approximately quantify the minimum number of changes needed to correct its syntax to some compilable code (regardless of whether the modified code is semantically correct or not)?
Here is my thinking, though I am not sure if there is a better way to think about it (hence, asking here.) To me, that sounds like an optimal transport problem - what is the minimal number of changes to move from an invalid to a valid string. In theory, the Wasserstein metric would be what you want, under the constrained optimization that (1) minimizes the edit distance (2) subject to being syntactically correct. For each bad string, run a discrete optimizer (like SPSA) to find the best corresponding good string, then compute your final edit distances. In practice, how much data do you have? Not sure if this scales well.
